# I have added in a while loop to ensure input is valid but even if you enter the same thing it only accepts the answer the second time?

Tags: python

```
answer = input("\nDo you want to see the instruction? (y/n): ") 
while answer != ("y","n"):
    answer = input("\nThat answer is not valid. Try again: ") 
    if answer == "y":
        print("Instructions.")
        break`

    if answer == "n":
        break
```

The problem is this:

```
Do you want to see the instruction? (y/n): n

That answer is not valid. Try again: n

Do you want to play easy or hard version? (e/h):
```

I don't know why it only accepts it the second time and not the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You check your `answer` against a tuple `("y","n")`. You should just check if your `answer` is one of the tuple's elements:

```
while answer not in ("y", "n"):
```

Also you need to move printing of instructions outside the loop:

```
answer = input("\nDo you want to see the instruction? (y/n): ") 
while answer not in ("y", "n"):
    answer = input("\nThat answer is not valid. Try again: ") 
if answer == "y":
    print("Instructions.")
```

Comment: Also the if conditions should not be in the while loop or at the beginning of the while loop or otherwise even if `answer in ("y", "n")`is true it is asked a second time.